# Why Guid sent in DELETE is always the default value?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got this `HttpDelete` method in a Web Api :

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Guid id) <== {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
{
    //some code
    return Ok("{\"msg\":\"success\"}");
}
```

And this is my AJAX call :

```
function deletePatient(idPatient) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/Patient',
        method: 'DELETE',
        async: false,
        data: idPatient, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Ok !");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Delete : Une erreur est survenue, merci de retenter plus tard.");
        }
    });
}
```

I'm initializing a datatable with `fnRowCallback` for call `deletePatient` like :

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    var idPatient = aData[4];
    if (idPatient != null) {
        $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html('<img id="' + idPatient + '"  onclick="deletePatient(&quot;' + idPatient + '&quot;);" src="../images/delete.png" />');
    }
}
```

When I debug the Guid received in the `Delete` method I only get the default value for a Guid : `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`.

Where is my mistake, can someone help me please ?

Thanks.

**EDIT** :

With postman, it works fine (raw, JSON(application/json))  :

> url : api/Patient/d4fee000-aa6a-4673-81cc-33e990509d73

The exact url :

[image]

Comment: Don't you need `{ id: idPatient }` for your data (since it seems to be a query parameter)?

Comment: @FrancoisBorgies Either show us how `idPatient` looks like, or try `data:{id:idPatient}`

Comment: Aside from the issue, remove `async: false`. It's very bad practice. If you need more specific help, please show us how you're retrieving the `idPatient` value, as that's the relevant part of the problem

Comment: Could you please show the structure of the posted object `idPatient`

Comment: It looks like all you need to to is to post `{ "id": idPatient }` in your AJAX

Comment: no reason just a misunderstanding of the process and i edit my question after i succeed the postman's call but indeed the first try (to make the call like i made it first) does'nt works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I modify a little bit my call :

```
function deletePatient(idPatient) {
    var url = "api/Patient/" + idPatient;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Ok !");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Delete : Une erreur est survenue, merci de retenter plus tard.");
        }
    });
}
```

and my http delete method to catch correctly the Id :

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
{...}
```

Thank you all for your help it works perfectly now.

Comment: why do you need to pass ` data: { id: idPatient }, ` it is already in the url

Comment: one point for you ;-)